# Flex Mobile: Test Resolutions Greater than Screen Size

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, android-emulator, flash-builder

Flash Builder has an Emulator for mobile devices of any resolutions.

My questions are the following:
1) When testing for devices with resolutions greater than my screen size, is it still reliable to use the FB Emulator?
2) What are other alternatives that can I use for debugging purposes with FB?

Comment: You can always use the various Android emulators (and Google's Android emulator, even though it is so slow that I would go with a 3rd party one) and on OS-X you can also use the Xcode/iPhone simulator to debug AIR apps...   Adobe's AIR Debug Launcher does a good job of resolution emulation. They all do a good job of device resolution emulation (in terms of accurate scaling to your actual screen size, but in the end, of course, physical device testing is the only true test for your app.

Comment: how bout AIR Debug emulator? is it okay for big resolutions (greater than my screen)?

Comment: That 'emulator' works fine, all any of the emulators are doing is scaling up or down while maintaining the "true" aspect ratio of the original resolution. I'm not sure what your true concern of resolutions great then your screen size is, do you have a particular use-case that you are concerned about?

Comment: well like for example... i tried the emulator with 1920x1080 for LG G2 device and so far, I can see the same on the actual mobile.. My concern is for bigger resolutions such as S6 (2560x1440) and others.. Was working on optimizing my AIR App since clients noticed the app to be too small on their mobile, but I have no actual device that I can use. However my screen size is just 1920x1080, was just wondering if it will affect the scaling.

Comment: How are you handling scaling within your app?  i.e. are you just scaling everything bigger or are you resizing UI controls, font sizes, changing their individual position, showing additional content, etc... are you using flex mobile-based Skins to handle UI scaling, etc..   either way, the emulated device size should show you areas that you are not handling correctly when the device resolution changes. Are you following Adobe's Guidelines? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS19f279b149e7481c682e5a9412cf5976c17-8000.html

Comment: i used auto scaling by setting the applicationDPI.. but  I have custom areas where i made adjustments with scaleX and scaleY. I think we are following the guidelines.. was just hoping that there's a way that we can do this in responsive manner other than creating multiple views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative to Capabilities since on FB Simulator it will use the monitor screen size not the actual device resolution.

```
var root:DisplayObject = SystemManager.getSWFRoot(this);                
screenX  = root.stage.fullScreenWidth;
screenY  = root.stage.fullScreenHeight;
```